# Giving arguments to maven resources goal from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, tomcat7

I'm using the Maven2 and Tomcat plugins for eclipse for a java project that gets deployed as a Tomcat app. I have several Run Configurations for a different goals, but I have one in particular that does multiple goals in sequence:

```
clean resources:resources compile war:war tomcat:deploy
```

I wanted one of my resource xml files to have config values specific to the build, for instance a dev-build versus a production-build. The `resources:resources`step should allow me to set values to {tags} in the xml, and I am able to do this via the command line as it's own step:

```
<test var="{foo}">
```

Running `mvn resources:resources -Dfoo='bar'` produces the following in the target directory

```
<test var="bar">
```

In the Run Configuration management gui in eclipse, there are slots for arguments and values, but I can't find the correct combination/incantation of parameters to get the same effect as the command line evocation.

Anyone know how?
Of course, would also accept "You're doing it wrong," (because I probably am) " Do it like this."

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can pass in parameters that are eventually used as [Maven properties](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties), using the parameters section of a Maven Build run configuration in Eclipse (I'll assume that you're using the Eclipse [M2E plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)).

The following screenshot demonstrates how the `{jacoco.agent.path}` property that I eventually used in my Maven POM, is specified from the run configuration:

[image: Eclipse Maven parameters]

Comment: Yes, but maven builds don't run tomcat. At least I can't figure out how to get it to.

Comment: Thanks! It would be good to mention that parameters specified this way don't need the `-D` prefix, but you still need to double any backslashes (_e.g._ `C:\\path\\to\\location`)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Run Configurations > Apache Tomcat > [your tomcat] > Arguments Tab > VM Arguments
And add -Dfoo="bar", it should work.

I had to stop and start and clean a few times before it picked it up, but it worked for me eventually.

Comment: Also, make sure you can override from the command line. If you can't, switch to a version of maven resources plugin that has this working. For me, 2.5 didn't allow property overriding from CLI but 2.4 did.